# Writing object array to file

Tags: java, arrays, file, object

I have problem writing object array into file in JAVA..this object array contains integer values..

```
Collections.shuffle(list);
r = (Object[])list.toArray();
```

I tried writing this object array "r" to file like this..

```
fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile,true);
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(r);
oos.close();
```

Everything is fine..but weird chars appear in the file..how to get it to write integer values?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Java, C#, pray tell what is the language

Comment: Im sorry...its java...

Comment: @user2784307: Please add the language as a tag to your question.

Comment: @user2784307 - It is getting serialized into binary. i.e. more efficient than ASCII. If you want ASCII it is a DIY job

Comment: How is the file going to be used? Is it actually meant to be read by humans (thus you want to see numbers, characters `0` to `9`)? Or is it meant to store data for your program to load again at a later time (in which case the "weird chars" might be just fine)?

Comment: @Mapper read by humans...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to write integers I'm thinking as text and not binary data, you need to convert the integers to text first, using a toString operation and then write the resulting string to file.

Comment: So I should read one by one from the object array and try writing it like..dos.write(Integer.toString(i).getBytes("UTF-8"));..no other way?

Comment: You don't have to do it one by one perhaps.  Sometimes you can generalize. For instance, you could make a toString function for the class that converts the integers to text.

Comment: I think there may not be a way to do it with a single command cause the language perhaps doesn't expect you to store numbers as text.

Answer (score 0):

How about a loop? That also gives you more control over the formatting.

Comment: You mean reading each integer from the array and writing it...guess that's onlu option left now..I'll better do that..

Comment: yes. writeObject, which you used, is to store objects in a file if you want to load them into your program later, but this write everything in a compact way and not in a human-readable form.